# Oracle PL/SQL - DECODE statement

Tags: sql, plsql

Both columns should be used: Customer_num is first, but if null, then use the Vendor_num.

To be more specific, I need to write a DECODE statement that will return the following:

If Customer_num IS NOT NULL then return Customer_num 
If Customer_num IS NULL then return Vendor_num 
If Vendor_num IS NULL Or If Customer_num IS NULL then return Customer_num

How can I do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [COALESCE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php)

COALESCE(Customer_num , Vendor_num)

Note this last requirement

> If Vendor_num IS NULL Or If Customer_num IS NULL then return Customer_num

Will either retrun Customer_num (because of the first requirement) or NULL when they are both null.

Comment: Not to worry, I figured it out by myself using NVL(DECODE(..)). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other posters that the "better" way to do this is to use NVL or COALESCE.  However, although I didn't expect this to work it appears that the following will do what you asked:

```
SELECT DECODE(CUSTOMER_NUM,
                 NULL, DECODE(VENDOR_NUM,
                                NULL, CUSTOMER_NUM,
                                      VENDOR_NUM),
                       CUSTOMER_NUM)
  FROM DUAL;
```

What's odd is that we can use DECODE to compare a value to NULL and have it return (apparently) TRUE.  In my mind the code above is conceptually the same as

```
IF CUSTOMER_NUM = NULL THEN
  IF VENDOR_NUM = NULL THEN
    RETURN CUSTOMER_NUM;
  ELSE
    RETURN VENDOR_NUM;
  END IF;
ELSE
  RETURN CUSTOMER_NUM;
END;
```

Apparently DECODE is bright enough to perform comparisons to NULL as if an IS NULL clause was used.  Thanks for posing this interesting little problem.

Comment: Thanks, wrapping the `DECODE` statement in `SELECT ` ... `FROM DUAL` worked fine for me, even though it would probably be cleaner to use `CASE` instead.

Comment: @peterp - I agree that CASE would be much clearer but the OP specifically wanted to use DECODE.

Comment: I know, that's why I gave you +1, just added this as additional info, for those who are not too lazy to get rid of the `DECODE` statement. (I was ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not **that** clear.

But you could try using [`nvl`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php):

```
select nvl(customer_num, vendor_num)
  from your_table;
```

Comment: Not to worry, I figured it out by myself using NVL(DECODE(..)). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 SELECT coalesce( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n )
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: It is not I was looking for, but still thanks. I figured it out by myself using DECODE. I wasn't aware about COALESCE, up until now. Thanks again.